# NSPredicate to fetch last message for each conversation in core data

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I have an entity named `messages` with the following attributes:
 -> `message_id`, `message_from`, `message_to`, `message_body`, `date_created`.

I want to fetch the last `message` for each user like we have in WhatsApp chat.

I found the following code for `MySQL`, but don't know how to use it with `NSPredicates`:

```
SELECT *
FROM messages m1
WHERE date_created = (SELECT MAX(m2.date_created)
                      FROM messages m2
                      WHERE m1.message_from = m2.message_from
                        AND m1.message_to = m2.message_to)
```

Could someone please help me to get the last message for each user from core data using `NSPredicate`?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need a method that extracts all Messages and all Users. For simplicity put it in your AppDelegate.m. Note that getAllMessages gets unique results by extracting data as a NSDictionary which by definition does not allow duplicate keys

```
-(NSArray*)getAllUsers
{
    // initializing NSFetchRequest
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    //Setting Entity to be Queried
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Message"
                                          inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    fetchRequest.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;
    fetchRequest.returnsDistinctResults = YES;
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    [fetchRequest setPropertiesToFetch:@[@"userId"]];
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"date_created" ascending:NO]];

    NSError* error;

    // Query on managedObjectContext With Generated fetchRequest
    NSArray *fetchedRecords = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    // Returning Fetched Records
    return fetchedRecords;
}

-(NSArray*)getAllMessages
{
    // initializing NSFetchRequest
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    //Setting Entity to be Queried
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Message"
                                          inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"date_created" ascending:NO]];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSError* error;

    // Query on managedObjectContext With Generated fetchRequest
    NSArray *fetchedRecords = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    // Returning Fetched Records
    return fetchedRecords;
}
```

Then you can extract and put the last message for each user in a NSMutableArray by doing this:

```
AppDelegate * appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSMutableArray * arrayUsers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[appDelegate getAllUsers]];
NSMutableArray * arrayMessages = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[appDelegate getAllMessages]];

NSMutableArray * lastMessageForEachUser = [NSMutableArray array];//on this array you get the results 
for (NSDictionary * dict in arrayUsers)
{
    NSNumber * userId = [dict objectForKey:@"userId"];
    NSPredicate * pr = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"userId == %@",userId];
    NSArray * results = [arrayMessages filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pr];
    Message * lastMessage = results.count>0 ? [results objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
    [lastMessageForEachUser addObject:lastMessage]; 
}
```

Comment: I want to fetch last messages for all the users and I don't know which users are present in the table. So, I can't check it with 'userId'.